# Teradata -Duplicate entries elimination while aggregating

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to eliminate the duplicates when aggregating the data.

```
CREATE  TABLE abc
( dt DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
,acct NUMBER
,chk_lmt VARCHAR(10)
,baln_lmt VARCHAR(10)
,wk DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD'
) ;
    INSERT  INTO abc
('2018-03-19' , 1001, 'under 1000' , 'under 500', '2018-03-23');

INSERT  INTO abc
('2018-03-20' , 1001, 'under 1000' , 'under 500', '2018-03-23');

INSERT  INTO abc
('2018-03-20' , 1002, 'under 1000' , 'under 500', '2018-03-23');

SELECT  dt,wk,'chk_lmt_chk' AS TYPEs, 
SUM ( CASE  WHEN chk_lmt = 'under 1000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   ) AS counts
  FROM abc
  GROUP BY 1,2,3;

    dt  wk  TYPEs   counts
19/03/2018  23/03/2018  chk_lmt_chk 1
19/03/2018  23/03/2018  chk_lmt_chk 0
20/03/2018  23/03/2018  chk_lmt_chk 2
```

For the dt 20/03/2018, the count should be 1 since the acct is already captured in the 19/03/2018.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How is this 2nd row calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL QUESTION.

If you want the account to be counted only once, the first time, use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT dt, wk, 'chk_lmt_chk' AS TYPEs, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN chk_lmt = 'under 1000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS counts
FROM (SELECT abc.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acct ORDER BY dt) as seqnum
      FROM ptemp.abc
     ) abc
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that helped. Ive edited the original requirement, is it possible to bring the record with count 0 also in the resultset ?

Comment: @user2653353 . . . I have no idea what the logic is for that.  It is rather rude to change the question after it has been answered -- that can invalidate the answer and draw downvotes.  If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Comment: am sorry. posting new question